# Storing the output of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes in Postgres using php? I get an error: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: php, postgresql, cryptography

I'm generating a salt using the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` function in php. However, I am unable to store the output into a PostgreSQL database.

I get an error:

> ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Now I realize the encoding of the database in question is set to UTF8, and that the output of the function doesn't match, **but what is the correct way of solving this?**

**This is a random salt, and I'm worried that converting it to UTF8 via whatever process will not make it cryptographically safe anymore?**

Comment: It is binary data, so treat it as such. That means LOB in PDO or equivalent in the adapter of your choice.

Comment: Converting to UTF8 is operation on text data, it has nothing to do with binary data. You haven't shown your code but it seems you have error in that - you are trying to convert binary into string.

Comment: OK, yeah, I'm trying to store it in a column that is a data type of VARCHAR, so I guess I need to change the data type. What is the most appropriate?

Comment: see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-binary.html

Comment: OK cool, I was busy checking out bytea but wasn't 100% it was the correct data type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` function outputs binary data, and I was trying to store the output in a database field of data type character varying, mistakenly treating it like a string.

`bytea` is the correct data type for the field in the PostgreSQL database.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/datatype-binary.html

Update: Also, it seems you need to use `pg_escape_bytea` on the output to be able to actually insert the binary data into the database.

Thanks to **deceze**, **lechlukasz**, and **VolkerK** in the comments for providing the answer.