# PHP pg_unescape_bytea producing different results on different machines

Tags: php, postgresql

OK, so this question is related to one I asked previously:
[Storing the output of openssl_random_pseudo_bytes in Postgres using php? I get an error: invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241827/storing-the-output-of-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes-in-postgres-using-php-i-get-a). Which was answered, but now I've encountered another issue.

I'm using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` to generate a salt, I then add that to the users password and hash the entire thing.

I then use `pg_escape_bytea` on the salt so that I can insert / store the value into a PostgreSQL database. This much works fine. Now to retrieve the salt when needed, I get it from the database, and use `pg_unescape_bytea` on the salt to get the original raw value that was used to create the hashed password.

Now I've found that on another machine, the `pg_unescape_bytea` salt value is different, even though the exact same code is running, with the same version of PHP, from the very same database.

How is this possible? Surely if the same code is running, off the exact same database, it should be identical?

**Should I not be unescaping the salt from the database after it is inserted, perhaps it is returned unescaped?**

**Or should I be first escaping the salt (using `pg_unescape_bytea` or `base64_encode` ?) on the salt BEFORE combining it to the password?**

Update with example:

```
$password = 'mypassword';

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30);

$pepper = 'pepper';

// Perhaps I should be performing a pg_escape_bytea on the salt before doing this?
$password_hash = hash('sha512', $password . $salt . $pepper);

// Adds the user to the database
$result = $data->add($email, $password_hash, pg_escape_bytea($salt), $company_id, $role_id);
```

Then when fetching the salt from the database:

```
// ...some code 

// ...last step when fetching the salt from the database.
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result, 0);

$row = pg_unescape_bytea( $row['salt'] ); // This value outputted produces different results
```

Also, I should note:

On one machine, the salt after being unescaped looks like gobbledygook, like non-UTF characters or something, which is what I'd expect when representing binary.

But on the other machine, unescaped salt looks practically identical to the escaped salt. Minus a `\`

**Example:**

Escaped salt: \x34e21

Unescaped salt: x34e21

**Versions:**

PHP version: 5.3.13

PostgreSQL version: 9.1

Comment: I've seen a couple of other reports related to PHP's `pg_escape_bytea` that make me wonder if it's doing the right thing or if there's a bug on some systems. You need to check the setting of `bytea_output` on both servers and their Pg driver versions, it's possible the server is producing `hex` and an outdated driver doesn't know to expect that so it's interpreting it as octal escapes. Please show the input and both the outputs so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: Personally I'd strongly recommend that you use proper parameterized statements instead of relying on `pg_escape` functions and string concatenation. That lets the driver take care of all the mess and reduces the chances of a small mistake resulting in a potential SQL injection hole.

Comment: Anyway, please show *the exact code*, the input and both outputs, both PHP versions and both PostgreSQL versions.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Please see the code example. I will be moving all the my code to proper parametized statements, but I didn't realize it would also automatically take care of stuff like this? Thought it was just more robust in general terms and prevented SQL injection.

Comment: It's true that I can't speak for PHP specifically; in languages that differentiate between byte sequences and text strings the SQL driver can usually examine the values passed and do appropriate conversion for the server. I just looked into it and found that PHP does not differentiate between encodingless byte-sequences and text strings, so it's likely you'll have to use a different function to set bytea and string parameters.

Comment: Oh, Pg expects hex-escaped bytea (Pg 9.0 or greater with `bytea_output` set to `escape`) or special octal-escaped strings (older versions). It does not use `base64` for bytea.

Comment: I's suggest you use Postgresql's pg_crypto extension to store encrypted users password, it has several functions just made for that purpose.

Comment: @CraigRinger What I've actually done now, is run `bin2hex` on the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` output before using it as a salt, and storing it into the database. I just hope the conversion doesn't make it cryptographically unsafe. It is consistent however. This might be the cleanest answer, and then move to the driver for queries.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate guess is that you have an old libpq on one of the servers which can't properly handle the hex encoding of the bytea.  If you are going to hex encode bytea, you might consider just unencoding it directly in PHP to save yourself the effort.

Obviously without a lot more information we can't say for sure, but the simple solution in PHP regardless of the problem is to check for \x at the beginning of the returned string and if it is, strip that off, and then convert hex to binary.